# Where do I find versions of Turnkey Linux made to run on 32-bit VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

What I found on the main site turnkeylinux.org/core is the file turnkey-core-12.1-squeeze-amd64-vmdk.zip which I suppose is for 64-bit OSes (corrections accepted..).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Turnkey 13.0 ISO for i386 here, http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/core-rc-wheezy. Specifically [turnkey-core-13.0rc-wheezy-i386.iso](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/download?file=turnkey-core-13.0rc-wheezy-i386.iso).

If you absolutely want 12.1 squeeze you can get it here, [turnkey-core-12.1-squeeze-i386.iso](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/download?file=turnkey-core-12.1-squeeze-i386.iso)

Comment: So, did the fact that my last download had "amd64" was the problem? I would also love it if you clarify what is meant by squeeze for me...

Comment: @spartacus - yes. amd64 is for 64-bit. The links I provided are the 32-bit versions. Also the names wheezy and squeeze tell you what version of Debian these distros are derived from. See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Debian_release_code_names

Answer (score 0):

The ISOs of both supported architectures (x86 - 32 & 64 bit) can be found on the Turnkey Linux SourceForge download page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/turnkeylinux/files/iso/

For installing on VirtualBox you could also try the VMDK builds (unzip and add the VMDK vHDD to a new VM) here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/turnkeylinux/files/vmdk/